# For loop in bash to input a new file in directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, bioinformatics

For context: I am running Prokka (as a novice bioinformatician with no Prokka and little Bash experience) and I have multiple FASTA files.

I have been told I need to produce a Bash loop that will allow me to input the FASTA files 1 by 1.

For example: my directory with all the FASTA (.fna) files is called StaphFNA, it has 1000 FASTA files in there. They are all named with ID numbers - but they do not increment as normal (so they aren't numbered 1, 2, 3 etc) there are random jumps e.g., one first be 34872 and the next one is 8933.

I need the first FASTA file within StaphFNA to be inputted, processed in Prokka, then outputted to a file called 'StaphProkka', then the 2nd FASTA file to go through the same process - being outputted into 'StaphProkka' again. On and on until all 1000 are complete.

As you can imagine, its a bit laborious having to do this 1000 times, so I wish to make a loop, but I am new to bash and I am struggling.

My Prokka argument (which I believe to be correct):

```
prokka /Users/me/Documents/StaphFNA --outdir StaphProkka --prefix staph_aur --kingdom bacteria --locusting staphylococcus
```

My For loop (which I know is wrong):

```
i = 0
for i in StaphFNA/.fna*; do
    prokka /Users/me/Documents/StaphFNA/$i --outdir StaphProkka --prefix staph_aur --kingdom bacteria --locusting staphylococcus
i = i + 1
done
```

Comment: Do you need to specify an output file name or does prokka do it for you? If, for example, you run `prokka foo.fna --outdir StaphProkka`, does that create a file called `StaphProkka/foo.prokka` or similar?

Comment: Remove `i = 0` and remove `i = i + 1`. Also if you want to test first, write `echo` in front of `prokka`. It will show all commands that will be run when you do it without `echo`

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic and welcome here, but you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to specify an output file and prokka produces differently named files based on its input, all you need is:

```
for file in /Users/me/Documents/StaphFNA/*.fna; do
    prokka "$file" \ 
        --outdir StaphProkka \
        --prefix staph_aur \
        --kingdom bacteria \
        --locusting staphylococcus 
done
```

The `for variable in dir/*` pattern will iterate over every file or directory in `dir/` and save its pathname as `$variable`, so you don't need a counter or anything else. If you did need to use a counter, for example to deal with `file1.fa`, `file2.fa` etc, and didn't want to also deal with `otherfile.fa`, you would so something like this (note the lack of spaces around the `=`, that's iportant):

```
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++)); do
    someCommand "file${i}.fa"
done
```

Or, if you need to explicitly increment the counter (which is rare), you could do:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    echo someCommand "file${i}.fa"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Comment: Should be `[ "$i" -le 10 ]`...`i=$(( i + 1 ))` (sh) or `(( i <= 10 ))` ... `(( i++ ))` (ksh/zsh/bash)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you mean the quotes? OK, but since we are controlling the value here, it didn't seem too important. As for the rest, I used `(( i++ ))` yes, since this is tagged `bash`. Am I missing something else?

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)  (especially the part after *exasperating* :-) You're controlling the value, but there's still no reason to invoke split+glob, and you don't know what the value of `$IFS` will be in all contexts wherever that code will be used.

Comment: Ha! Fair enough, @StéphaneChazelas, I certainly don't want to exasperate you :) And you'll notice I have quoted it already after your last comment. I was just wondering if this isn't one of the few, 100% safe cases given that I include a `i=0` just there, so it seems to me that there is no way the lack of quotes could possibly cause an issue. Am I wrong?

Comment: You've not read the part after *exasperating*, have you?

Comment: Not carefully enough, @StéphaneChazelas, no. I get it now, thanks.